# When I try to open a game exported as runtime, my computer gives me an error

Tags: game-engine, export

The error says, "MyGame is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Trash." I've done everything that the blender wiki says.

PS: I'm on blender 2.76b

Comment: please specify at least your OS type, version, and maybe some details about your "game", etc.

Comment: I assume that you are using the game publishing addon, it that correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Mac (sounds like you are I've gotten that same error) it's just because you need to enable all apps to be openable. System Preferences > General > Security and Privacy > allow apps from anywhere
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, I had the same problem try deleting all your .dll files in the run time folder (note: don't delete anything in other folder and don't delete the .exe only the files named [FileName].dll) . Go in c:/ program files/blender foundation/2.76 (note: this folder is not always there,but if it is there go into it) and copy (note: don't cut) all the .dll only and past the .dll file in your run time folder (note: don't past it in any other folder in the folder).

Sorry for all the notes